# Heap memory size of the DLL loaded via .NET Interop

Tags: .net, memory-management, dll, interop, win32-process

I have a generic C++ dll which in which I have few structures. I am passing the structure data from the C#.net console based application and and I am trying to deep copy that structure inside my dll like a copy constructor.

my problem is it seems the dll is running out of memory while allocating the memory using new after few allocations!! is there any heap memory allocation limitation for the generic dll's consumed by .net applications?

Solutions -
I have tried creating my own heap using `::heapcreate()` and used this handle to create my objects using `new` and it seems to work, whats not working is using normal operator `new` and deep copying structure with lots of `wchar_t*` on the deafault heap.

Any help or any information regarding memory allocations for the generic dll's consumed by .NET would really really help.

Comment: No such limitation.  If you can allocate memory with another heap then it isn't failing on an out-of-memory condition.  It fails because the heap is corrupted.